# Trying to implement Data.Either

Tags: haskell, functor, either

To help me learn Applicative Functors and Functors I thought it would be good fun to see how `Either` is implemented with the typeclasses `Functor` and `Applicative`. Obviously I could just go ahead and read the code but I find it more useful to try and implement things myself to get a better understanding of things.

FYI I'm trying to implement the Haskell version of the results of this presentation http://applicative-errors-scala.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/0.6/chunk-html/index.html

Anyway, this is what I have so far

```
 data Validation a b = Success a | Failure b deriving (Show, Eq)

 instance Functor (Validation a) where
     fmap f (Failure x) = Failure x
     fmap f (Success x) = Success (f x)
```

But whenever I try to run this with `ghci` I just get the following error message: -

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( t.hs, interpreted )

t.hs:5:35:
    Couldn't match type `b' with `a1'
      `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            fmap :: (a1 -> b) -> Validation a a1 -> Validation a b
          at t.hs:4:5
      `a1' is a rigid type variable bound by
           the type signature for
             fmap :: (a1 -> b) -> Validation a a1 -> Validation a b
           at t.hs:4:5
    Expected type: a
      Actual type: b
    In the return type of a call of `f'
    In the first argument of `Success', namely `(f x)'
    In the expression: Success (f x)

t.hs:5:37:
    Couldn't match type `a' with `a1'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the instance declaration at t.hs:3:30
      `a1' is a rigid type variable bound by
           the type signature for
             fmap :: (a1 -> b) -> Validation a a1 -> Validation a b
           at t.hs:4:5
    In the first argument of `f', namely `x'
    In the first argument of `Success', namely `(f x)'
    In the expression: Success
```

I'm not really sure why this is, can anyone help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're trying to make the `Functor` instance work on the `Success` part, which is the normal thing to do, but because of the order of your type parameters it is being defined on the type in the `Failure` part instead.

Since you've defined it as

```
data Validation a b = Success a | Failure b

instance Functor (Validation a) where
    ...
```

This means that your implementation of `fmap` should have the type `(x -> y) -> Validation a x -> Validation a y`. But since the second type variable is for the `Failure` case, this does not type check.

You want the type variable for the `Success` case to be the last one instead:

```
data Validation b a = Success a | Failure b
```

Comment: Ahhh I see, thanks, I'm presuming `data Validation a b = Failure a | Success b deriving (Show, Eq)` would also be correct. Thanks!

Comment: @djworld: Yep. That's just the same thing with the names of the type variables and the order of the constructors swapped.

Comment: @djhworld: And now you also understand why, in `Either a b`, `Left` represents the failure case (not just because it isn't the "right" result).